# Is there any built in function in python / matplotlib for labeling the grids touched by a line?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am simulating the result of a scientific paper (using python and matplotlib) where it is required to color the 2D grids touched by line. I have the starting (x1, y1) and ending (x2, y2) points to draw the line. These points (x1, x2, y1, y2) can be of floating numbers. A pic is attached to describe the scenario:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDotB.jpg

[image]

I have already tried to use a python library of bresenham algorithm (to find out almost all the grids touched by a line, https://github.com/encukou/bresenham/ ) but this library can only take integer coordinates as argument. My input can be of floating number ( (3.2, 2.85), (4.5, 3.33) )

Is there any built in implementation in python to do that? If not, how can I modify the library (https://github.com/encukou/bresenham/ ) to accomodate my requirement? Please note that, using bresenham algorithm is not mandatory.

Comment: Just a heads up that Bresenham's algorithm is not guaranteed to give you all grids cells touched by a line. It just determines a "good-enough" representation of a line using grid cells. What you seem to be looking for is referred to as the line supercover. I am not aware of an implementation in python for floating point coordinates. In many ways, however, the problem is very similar to ray tracing for axis aligned bounding boxes (AABB). If you can't find a line supercover implementation for floats, I would start there.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2232) is a figure showing the difference between Bresenham's approximation and the line supercover.